# Add page number to meta title on paginated pages Wordpress, Yoast

Tags: php, html, wordpress, pagination, yoast

I know this kind of questions has been asked many time before, I have read all post on web, none of answers meet my need.

I'm not able to add page numbers to meta title on paginated pages, including homepage and taxonomy, with yoast plugin (to avoid duplicate content with search engine).

I'm using custom meta title and description, I tried to add the tag %%page%% directly on custom meta title, but it's not working.

My theme is using the new feature: add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

This is the head on header.php file:

```
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><![endif]--  >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php print get_template_directory_uri();?    >/assets/js/ie8/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="<?php print get_template_directory_uri();?    >/assets/js/ie8/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->    
<?php wp_head();?>
</head>
```

Please help, there are many people with the same issue, since the change to: add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Update:
In the theme there is a file: content-page.php, 
and looks like this:

```
<div class="post-header">
<h2>
<?php the_title();?>
</h2>
</div>
<div class="post-entry">
<?php the_content();?>
<?php 
$defaults = array(
'before' => '<ul class="pagination">',
'after' => '</ul>',
'before_link' => '<li>',
'after_link' => '</li>',
'current_before' => '<li class="active">',
'current_after' => '</li>',
'previouspagelink' => '&laquo;',
'nextpagelink' => '&raquo;'
);  
bootstrap_link_pages( $defaults );
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For custom meta title, you can use yoast hook,

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'add_meta_title', 10, 1);
function add_meta_title($title){
 //add meta title

return $title;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. Just added your code on function.php file, does not work for me, all custom meta titles are still without page numbers. 
I can see some of category which are not custom, is showing the meta title tags: page 2 of 6 and so on.. as it is set on yoast with the tag %%page%%, this setting it's also on pages, but just doesn't work. 
If possible I would like to add like: page 2, page 3, and so on.. rather then page 1 of 8.